# Russian "Turist" bike look alike

Tags: road-bike, replacement, bike-selection, europe

guys! I was wondeing if any of you beautiful people can help me out. My dad's bike just broke :( He lives in Ukraine and has had this "Turist" bike for probably over 20 years. They don't make this model anymore and I was looking around on the internets trying to find a similar looking bike to buy for him. He's 60 and uses it to commute to work and when going on fishing trips. I have attached a picture. If you know where I could find a bike that look like it, or even better, where I could buy one and have it delivered to Kiev, Ukraine, I would greatly appreciate it :)
Please post a model number and I can look into it and where to buy it.
Thanks so much[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoyC7.jpg)

Comment: HVZ bikes are dime and dozen all across ex-USSR, you can get another Tourist for cheap or spare parts for even cheaper, especially in Ukraine. What exactly has broken? Also, I'd advise to visit [HT HVZ subforum](http://xt.ht/phpbb/viewforum.php?f=31).

Comment: @Klaster_1,  whoa! Thanks so much! That's awesome :) I made a thread in the forum, but it asked me to put down price that I'm willing to pay and I have no idea what they go for %\ .... But thanks, that's really helpful :)

Comment: Here in Russia you can find Tourist for 1500-5000 RUB.

Comment: @Klaster_1, wow, that's really cheap. Thanks for the info!

Comment: That looks like a fairly conventional 1980s US road bike, aside from the fact that the US bike would have a front derailer.  It's virtually identical to my old Nishiki.  I wouldn't expect you'd have a hard time replacing it unless you insisted on something from the same era vs a more modern model.

Comment: Note that the tricky part is finding a bike to fit him, without him having an opportunity to test-ride it.  He might be able to help in this regard by sending you measurements from the current bike, particularly "standover" height,  seat tube length and the distance from the center of the crank to ground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Bicycles.SE, we're more aimed at helping you overcome practical problems.  Since its a nice looking bike, why not fix it?

Please tell us more about the problem/damage, with photos of the broken parts.

Comment: oh! I'm sorry! I just thought this would be the best place to ask because I don't know if there is a specific way to search for bicycles, like if what it looks like tells you something about where to find similar models. I just knew that it was a road bike, that's it, i'm quite uninformed in this area XD I will ask him to take some pictures and will post them here :)

Comment: Good stuff - I'm looking forward to more info (a.k.a. bike porn!)